# Tooltip on control focus ahk

Tags: autohotkey

In Autohotkey, is there a way to detect what gui control has focus so that I display a text box with basically a tooltip.

I want to hover my mouse or use the keyboard to navigate and display what would be stored in the tooltip in a multiline textbox.

I dont want to have a tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! ;-)

I watch if the mouse moves, or a control has focus and display in a text box some stored values

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, WatchCursor, 100
return

WatchCursor:
MouseGetPos, mx, my, id, mouseControl
ControlGetFocus, currentFocus, A

if (SubStr(mouseControl,1,6)= "Button" OR SubStr(currentFocus,1,6)= "Button")
    butIDkey := SubStr(currentFocus,7,2)
    butIDmouse := SubStr(mouseControl,7,2)

    if (SubStr(mouseControl,1,6)= "Button" && lastmx <> mx && lastmy <> my)
        butID := butIDmouse 

    if (butIDkey <> lastControl) 
        butID := butIDkey

    lastControl :=  butIDkey
    lastmx := mx
    lastmy := my

    GuiControl,TemplateEngine:, MyTooltip,  % Value%butID%
}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OnMessage(0x0200, "WM_MOUSEMOVE") ; WM_MOUSEMOVE 0x0200

Return

WM_MOUSEMOVE(wParam, lParam)
{
 global Control_Name
  X := lParam & 0xFFFF
  Y := lParam >> 16
 MouseGetPos, , , , Control_Name
 Tooltip, %Control_Name%, (x+150), (y+150)
}

Esc::ExitApp
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[ControlGetFocus](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGetFocus.htm) is used to get the name.  See sample code below

```
a::
ControlGetFocus, OutputVar, A
if ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, The target window doesn't exist or none of its controls has input focus.
else
    MsgBox, Control with focus = %OutputVar%
```

Comment: thx, I want to check for focus changes, e.g. If I hover over with the mouse or use keys to change focus how can i check for changes in realtime?